# Firing events based on table value on 'OnClose" Events

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know how to use the DLookup function, I know how to use the onclose event on reports as I use both extensively. However, I can't seem to get them to work together. With the help of Stackoverflow and some google, I can get all my questions answered. So, I am back!

This is my code. When I close a specific report, other forms will open, exports happen, etc. I won't bore you with the code for all that, I just can't figure out how to have an If statement based on a value in a table...and NOT get an error message.

```
Private Sub Report_Close()
If DLookup("Design Mode", "Database_Settings").Value = True Then
    MsgBox "True"
Else
    MsgBox "False"
End If
End Sub
```

This is a Yes/ No field I am referencing.
Jist...If the field is checked, true, do all the exporting and stuff. (Normal Operations). If the field is not checked, false, then just close the report. (When I use it). All the actions that run, have been working for a while now. I get an error message now since I added a referenced field from a table.

Thanks -j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
If Nz(DLookup("[Design Mode]", "[Database_Settings]"), False) Then
```

Comment: Thank you! Works beautifully!